# Keep text on foreground with scale effect on image

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image gallery with a hover effect. once the user hovers over the image it uses a css transform.

```
transform: scale(1.1);
```

The image looks like this without the hover effect.
[image]

and with the effect it looks like this.
[image]

As you can see it does zoom in nicely but somehow the text disapears in the background. I tried using z-index but this has no effect. How do I keep the text in the front?
Here is a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xk2us9q8/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The text will probably need `position:relative` for the `z-index` to be effective

Comment: Could you add this as the answer @Paulie_D ?

Comment: Answer added as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` requires a positioning value other than `static` to take effect.

Just add `position:relative` to the text.

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
p {
  color: white;
  width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-top: -90px;
  position: relative;
}
.dnnmedia_image {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.dnnmedia_image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x350/000/fff" class="dnnmedia_image" />
</div>
<p>
  Random text
</p>
```